# particles blown away from impact?

Tags: animation, particles

so I have an object that I have animated to fall onto a plane, and I want to have dust-like particles that are blown away from the impact like in a way that dust is. I don't know how I would achieve this effect, any help?

Comment: Sounds like a job for the molecular add-on. http://www.blendernation.com/2013/05/01/add-on-molecular/

Comment: You want the particles to fall on the plane and poof away, or just poof away as the emitter object falls?

Comment: The Idea would be that the particles are already there. Like debry that gets blown away from the impact @PGmath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider adding Collision objects and applying a force in the Physics tab.

Particles are affected/moved by a force.

[image]

In the image above the blue cone has Wind Force attached in the Physics tab.
Particles are being moved to the right.
Experiment with the forces as suits you.

[image]
Cyan Plane is collision object in the Physics in the image above.

Particle system from large yellow sphere.